# PromQL query to find timestamp of minimum (or maximum) reading

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm trying to query the timestamp of the minimum (or maximum) value of a series, for use in a stat panel in Grafana. I had read that this is difficult but [a workaround was posted in issue #8966](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/8966#issuecomment-874961630), which I am trying to use.

So let's say I have a metric called `temp` which is the temperature in Celsius. A query for the minimum reading in the last 12 hours looks like:

```
min_over_time(temp[12h])
```

Which produces the graph:

[image: Graph of minimum temperature in the previous 12 hours]

So that's fine; the minimum in the last 12 hours was 20.8°C. The workaround is to now filter for only readings that are the same as that:

```
scalar(min_over_time(temp[12h])) == temp
```

This however produces an empty result. Why is that? I would have thought that if min_over_time() pulls out a value then that value exists in at least one reading, so filtering for equality should leave me with at least one reading.

If it had worked, what I would be doing next according to the workaround would be to use an "`and`" to get the timestamp[s of all readings which match and then it would be a simple case of getting Grafana to use the most recent result. The full workaround would be:

```
timestamp(temp) and (scalar(min_over_time(temp[12h])) == temp)
```

Also, altering the time range does sometimes produce results and these results seem to be correct. It is only in the case where the equality filter produces no results that things go wrong.

Failing that approach, is there any alternative way to achieve what is wanted, that is, to get the timestamp of the minimum (or maximum) reading in a given range?

### What exactly is returned

In answer to the question of what exactly is being returned by Prometheus for each half of the "and":

(Only 1 hour of data for brevity)

```
$ curl -s "http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=scalar%28min_over_time%28temp%5B1h%5D%29%29" | jq
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "scalar",
    "result": [
      1669069334.632,
      "21.4"
    ]
  }
}
```

So 21.4 at 1669069334.632.

And the list of readings for the last hour:

```
$ curl -s "http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query_range?query=temp&start=$(expr $(date +%s) - 3600)&end=$(date +%s)&step=60" | jq
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "matrix",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "__name__": "temp",
          "channel": "1",
          "id": "159",
          "instance": "specialbrew",
          "job": "weathermqtt",
          "sensor": "MTU5LDEsUHJvbG9ndWUtVEg=",
          "subtype": "5"
        },
        "values": [
          [
            1669066155,
            "21.4"
          ],
          [
            1669066215,
            "21.4"
          ],
          [
            1669066275,
            "21.4"
          ],
          [
            1669066335,
            "21.4"
          ],
          [
            1669066395,
            "21.4"
          ],
          [
            1669066455,
            "21.4"
          ],
          [
            1669066515,
            "21.4"
          ],
          [
            1669066575,
            "21.4"
          ],
          [
            1669066635,
            "21.4"
          ],
          [
            1669066695,
            "21.4"
          ],
          [
            1669066755,
            "21.4"
          ],
          [
            1669066815,
            "21.4"
          ],
          [
            1669066875,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669066935,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669066995,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669067055,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669067115,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669067175,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669067235,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669067295,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669067355,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669067415,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669067475,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669067535,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669067595,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669067655,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669067715,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669067775,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669067835,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669067895,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669067955,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669068015,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669068075,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669068135,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669068195,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669068255,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669068315,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669068375,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669068435,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669068495,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669068555,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669068615,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669068675,
            "21.6"
          ],
          [
            1669068735,
            "21.7"
          ],
          [
            1669068795,
            "21.7"
          ],
          [
            1669068855,
            "21.7"
          ],
          [
            1669068915,
            "21.7"
          ],
          [
            1669068975,
            "21.7"
          ],
          [
            1669069035,
            "21.7"
          ],
          [
            1669069095,
            "21.7"
          ],
          [
            1669069155,
            "21.7"
          ],
          [
            1669069215,
            "21.7"
          ],
          [
            1669069275,
            "21.7"
          ],
          [
            1669069335,
            "21.7"
          ],
          [
            1669069395,
            "21.7"
          ],
          [
            1669069455,
            "21.7"
          ],
          [
            1669069515,
            "21.7"
          ],
          [
            1669069575,
            "21.7"
          ],
          [
            1669069635,
            "21.7"
          ],
          [
            1669069695,
            "21.7"
          ],
          [
            1669069755,
            "21.7"
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

There's at least one 21.4 in there so I expect some matches. But my query for `temp == scalar(min_over_time(temp[1h]))` gives me "Empty query result" in Prometheus. Though sometimes it does work. Is it looking for matches on *both* the timestamp and value? There are matches for "21.4" but not "1669069334.632".

Comment: When you are not getting data for the equality filter, what exactly are you getting for the query : (scalar(min_over_time(temp[12h])) ? Can you explain more on when you are not getting values here. Based on my testing the above logic should work fine.

Comment: @Isaiah4110 thanks for looking. I've edited the question to add the data that Prometheus is returning for each half of the "and" query.

Comment: One thing I figured as part of my research, the time you mentioned above: 1669069334.632 thats not the actual time when the value was 21.4 rather its the query execution time.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should return timestamps with the minimum temperature over the selected time range in Grafana:

```
timestamp(temp)
  and
(
  min_over_time(temp[$__interval]) == min_over_time(temp[$__range] @ end())
)
```

The `$__interval` is automatically substituted by Grafana with the interval between adjacent points on the graph - see [these docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.0/variables/variable-types/global-variables/#__interval). This value is known as a `step` arg, which is passed by Grafana to `/api/v1/query_range` endpoint provided by Prometheus - see [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries).

The `$__range` is automatically substituted by Grafana with the selected time range for the graph - see [these docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.0/variables/variable-types/global-variables/#__range).

The query above uses `@` modifier - see [this blogpost](https://prometheus.io/blog/2021/02/18/introducing-the-@-modifier/) for details about this modifier.

Note that the query above won't work as is when passed to Prometheus directly without substitution for `$__interval` and `$__range` args with proper durations.

P.S. The task of finding the timestamp with the minimum (maximum) value is solved much easier in VictoriaMetrics - Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on. It provides [tmin_over_time()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#tmin_over_time) and [tmax_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#tmax_over_time) functions, which return the timestamp for the minimum (maximum) raw value over the specified lookbehind window. For example, the following [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query returns the timestamp for the minimum temperature over the last 12 hours:

```
tmin_over_time(temp[12h])
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still returns empty results. In the Grafana query inspector it's `frames: Array[0] []`